# How do I tag the current git changeset from inside the Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I want to tag the current git changeset and push the tag from inside the Jenkinsfile. If the tag already exists it must be replaced.

I want to use this logic in order to tag the build that passed with the `snapshot` tag, which would be a mobile tag.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the way I was able to implement this this way, but if you know a better way I am more than willing to hear it.

```
#!groovy

stage 'build'
node {

    repositoryCommiterEmail = 'ci@example.com'
    repositoryCommiterUsername = 'examle.com'

    checkout scm

    sh "echo done"

    if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
        stage 'tagging'

        sh("git config user.email ${repositoryCommiterEmail}")
        sh("git config user.name '${repositoryCommiterUsername}'")

        sh "git remote set-url origin git@github.com:..."

        // deletes current snapshot tag
        sh "git tag -d snapshot || true"
        // tags current changeset
        sh "git tag -a snapshot -m \"passed CI\""
        // deletes tag on remote in order not to fail pushing the new one
        sh "git push origin :refs/tags/snapshot"
        // pushes the tags
        sh "git push --tags"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. How do you do authentication to the remote(how do you send the password)?

Comment: You should set up SSH key, so you don't have to input any password or have it stored anywhere.

Comment: Not an alternative answer, but a change of perspective : when you publish a -SNAPSHOT on Nexus, it doesnt remove the old -SNAPSHOT before uploading the new one, it keeps all snapshots using a timestamp. The same thing can be done very easily with git tags.

Answer (score 4):

For people that couldn't get the above working I used the sshagent plugin directly, which did the trick:

```
stage('tag build'){
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'git',
    url: 'ssh://<ssh URL>']],
    extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'targeted-dir']]
])

sshagent(credentials: ['<credentials ID.']){
  dir('targeted-dir'){
    sh("git config user.email '<email>")
    sh("git config user.name '<user>.com'")

    // deletes current snapshot tag
    sh ("git tag -d ${PARAM_VERSION_NUMBER} || true")
    // tags current changeset
    sh ("git tag -a ${PARAM_VERSION_NUMBER} -m \"versioning ${PARAM_VERSION_NUMBER}\"")
    // deletes tag on remote in order not to fail pushing the new one
    sh ("git push origin :refs/tags/snapshot")
    // pushes the tags
    sh ("git push --tags")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I want to share [my Jenkins Pipeline Setup](https://gist.github.com/amaksoft/b17408303d69c71498eaa39ea2ee3b01) and my solution to publish changes/tags to git repo via SSH (While [Git Publish Support](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335) is under development). Please check it out for more info, any improvement ideas are welcome.

In short you just add file `git_push_ssh.groovy` to your project and call method `pushSSH()` from Jenkinsfile like this:

```
env.BRANCH_NAME = "mycoolbranch"// BRANCH_NAME is predefined in multibranch pipeline job
env.J_GIT_CONFIG = "true"
env.J_USERNAME = "Jenkins CI"
env.J_EMAIL = "jenkins-ci@example.com"
env.J_CREDS_IDS = '02aa92ec-593e-4a90-ac85-3f43a06cfae3' // Use credentials id from Jenkins
def gitLib = load "git_push_ssh.groovy"
...
gitLib.pushSSH(commitMsg: "Jenkins build #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", tagName: "build-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", files: "changelog.txt someotherfile.txt");
```

Comment: I added the above example stage to clearly show how to add the tag, as it took me a little bit, looking at the example above the the linked code to get this working. It also requires the "ssh agent" plugin for jenkins to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

To get this working for blue ocean (which uses https connection) use the following:

```
sshagent(credentials: ["406ef572-9598-45ee-8d39-9c9a227a9227"]) {
                def repository = "git@" + env.GIT_URL.replaceFirst(".+://", "").replaceFirst("/", ":")
                sh("git remote set-url origin $repository")
                sh("git tag --force build-${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
                sh("git push --force origin build-${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The SSH-Agent-based approach didn't work on our Windows build server, however, we still wanted to use the credentials stored in Jenkins' credential manager. As our Git credential is an SSH key, we realized we could let Jenkins provide us with the keyfile directly:

```
stage("Tag") {
    steps {
        script {
            def tagName = "..."
            withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "idOfYourCredentials", keyFileVariable: "KEY")]) {
                def key = KEY.replaceAll("\\\\", "/") // Only needed on Windows
                env.GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -i ${key}"
                bat "git tag \"${tagName}\""
                bat "git push --tags"
            }
        }
    }
}
```