# Create git tag from within Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Within my Jenkins pipeline script, I would like to do something like this:

```
sh("git tag ${BUILD_NUMBER}")
```

However, this wouldn't work if git isn't found on the shell.

Is there any Jenkins plugin that can do this from a Jenkins pipeline script?

Comment: what about [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)

Comment: In my "Jenkins pipeline script" ...

Comment: to use the git command in a shell you need to have GIT on the path.

Comment: I don't need it on the path if I'm installing it automatically from Jenkins, which I am.

Answer (score 6):

There is no plugin support for this currently but might be in the future:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335

While you go over this Jira issue take a look at Andrey Makeev's temporary solution. also documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345850/how-do-i-tag-the-current-git-changeset-from-inside-the-jenkinsfile).

Comment: Rather than linking, you should go ahead and outline the solution here - this prevents link rot from making your otherwise "correct" answer unusable.

Comment: Thanks @rbellamy well noted. Since this is not my solution I didn't want to take credit for it.

Comment: that's attribution, which you can still do by including the link. Take a look at my answer and you'll see the format that's pretty much the accepted method for ensuring attribution AND preventing link rot.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I do it, where `shell` and `Version` are custom functions and class, respectively, and `shell` is a drop-in replacement for the `sh` function:

```
    void gitTag(Version releaseVersion) {
      sshagent(['devops_deploy_DEV']) {
        shell 'git tag -d \$(git tag)'
        shell 'git fetch --tags'
        echo "New release version ${releaseVersion.normalVersion}"
        shell "git tag -fa ${releaseVersion.normalVersion} -m 'Release version ${releaseVersion.normalVersion}'"
      }
    }
```

You can find the source for this [here](https://github.com/terradatum/jenkins-pipeline-library/blob/master/src/com/terradatum/jenkins/workflow/TerradatumCommands.groovy#L276).

Comment: This creates the git tag, but doesn't push it back to git server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Git-Client plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin) to make things like this:
`sh "git tag build_${gitCommit}"`

Comment: I have the plugin installed and I already tried this, but I'm getting `git: command not found`

Comment: This is not using the Git-Client plugin, just basic Git comand from your master/slave node.