# Git Tag for Jenkins after Releasing

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, gitlab, nexus

I'm using Jenkins,GitLab,Maven and Nexus for a project. Previously I did mvn build and nexus release artifact uploading using Jenkins shell commands. Now I have to create Git Tag for it. Can someone give the guidance for doing this. All the things I am using shell commands.Can I use these commands for it?

```
git tag -a v0.0.1 -m "0.0.1 tag"
git push origin v0.0.1
```

Comment: This question was answered at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357340/8442153).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo tagging with build-$BUILD_NUMBER
git tag -f build-$BUILD_NUMBER
git tag -l 
git remote -v
git remote set-url origin https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@hub.jazz.net/git/user/project
git push --tags origin
```

followed https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/187229/is-there-a-way-to-tag-a-commit-in-git-inside-of-a/